# Is there any way to merge relative cells in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, so, I use Excel to generate invoices for my business and VBA help me track my sales by automatically posting various details of invoices like Date, Invoice number, Buyer name and quantity.

The problem is there's only one cell for date, invoice number and buyer but the quantity takes my multiple rows, and due to which I have to manually select and merge the other cells.

Here's my code -

```
 Sub registerdrums()
   Set ws1 = Worksheets("performa")
   Set ws2 = Worksheets("billing")
    drum = ws1.Range("r25").Value
'if the item sold is drum
If drum = "WD" Then
'if the row which is next
nextrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1
' sold items
ws1.Range("p25:q45").Copy
ws2.Cells(nextrow, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
'date
ws2.Cells(nextrow, 1).Value = ws1.Range("E8")
'invoice number
ws2.Cells(nextrow, 2).Value = ws1.Range("E7")
'buyer code
ws2.Cells(nextrow, 3).Value = ws1.Range("Q20")
ws1.Activate
Else: If drum <> "WD" Then ws1.Activate
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Plese follow these guidelines if you want proper help from this community: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please add more details about the problem, so people will be able to help you.

Comment: can I inset a picture somehow?

Comment: Yes, edit your original question and there's options for inserting a picture.  I think copy pasting will also allow you to insert as picture.